# How do i return the value of how many times a certain integer appears in a list using a loop? How can I find the mode in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, integer

Write a program how_many.py

which has the following functions in it:
freq(n,l) which will be passed a list of integers l and a single integer n. It will return the frequency of which l appears, that is how many times it appears. So, freq(3,[3,2,2,1,3,4,5,4,3,4,3]) would return 4 since 3 appears 4 times. DO NOT USE COUNT -- loop through the list and do this manually.

min(l) -- calculates the smallest value of the list - again, do this manually using a loop not using a built in function.

mode(l) which returns the mode - the most frequently occurring item in the list - you can assume a single mode in the list, that is there won't be two items that appear the most times.

Yes this is my homework. No I do not want you guys doing it for me. i want to understand or have some type of help to GUIDE me to start this. I am entirely new to python and to the world of code, so it essential that I understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

**Title question**

**=====================================================**

Initialise a **counter** which counts how many times you find `n` in your list. Then you must step through each index in your array, and at each step, check that this value is the same as `n`

If it is, increment `n` by 1, if it isn't, do nothing. When you reach the end of your list, return the final result.

**=====================================================**

**Min(l)**

Initialise a variable which stores the minimum value **so far** called `min` as you are checking through the list. At each index of the list, check to see if the value at this index is bigger than `min`. If it is, update `min`'s value, otherwise do nothing. Return `min` when you get to the end of the list.

**=====================================================**

**Mode(l)**

The mode is the most frequently found number in the array. You must make a map of keys and values (your keys being the distinct numbers in your list, and value being how many times it appears). Once you have looped through your list and found out how many times they each appear, return the largest value in your new map.

**======================================================**

**good luck**